# What is JAVA exec()uting?

Tags: java, linux, exec, trace

I'm on Linux and I have a Java application (JAR archive) which is using exec() to do it's stuff. I need to find out which commands is that application exec()uting... I tried strace and jstack but without any results. Suppose that the app is calling exec("ls"), can I find that ls command just by grepping output of above programs?

So the question is: 
Is there a simple way to watch what is Java application executing with exec() ?

Edit for better situation overview:

Suppose that in Java app i have a button with onclick listener which calls static function from another class.In that function is `exec("ls");` called.
When I click that button I see this in strace:

`futex(0x7f14a6f799d0, FUTEX_WAIT, 4968, NULLDownload button clicked !
Trying SCP FROM...
 <unfinished ...>`

Trying SCP FROM.. is just my sout in that button handler right before calling `exec()`.

Another edit:
Thank you guys, but I'm talking from OS point of view... Suppose that I'm sysadmin and I downloaded JAR. I want to know (from outside) what is that JAR doing - I'm only interested in programs started from `exec()`

So I tried `strace` but it shows nothing about calling that command from exec... Maybe it is logging too much low level calls for this...

Then i tried `jstack -m` but I can't find anything looking like that command from exec. I tried grepping string but with no luck.

Comment: Shouldn't the `ls` process have the Java process as its parent, e.g. when looking at the output of `ps` etc.?

Comment: @Thomas: But that process will be alive only for a few milliseconds.

Comment: Hmm, nice idea... But that would be shown only if i run `ps` just in time when the ls command is executing. I would be happier with something like log or trace...

Comment: It has to show up in `strace`, right?

Comment: @Thilo Please, can you take a look on my updated question? Only thing I see in strace is <unfinished>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, what I'm going to propose is a **veeeeeeeeeery** rudimentary way of doing things, but it might be what you are looking for.

As you probably know, a `.jar` file is just a ZIP archive comprised of Java `.class` files. If you just need to get a peek at which commands are going to be executed, ***and*** if you know the class that is supposed to execute them, you can just extract the class files from the jar file with `gzip` and then use `strings` on them to look for commands.

For example, here's the most simple class I could think of that uses `exec()`:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/ls");
        } catch (IOException ignored) {}
    }
}
```

If you do `strings Main.class` you should get something like this:

```
[...]$ strings Main.class
<init>
Code
LineNumberTable
LocalVariableTable
this
LMain;
main
([Ljava/lang/String;)V
args
[Ljava/lang/String;
StackMapTable
SourceFile
        Main.java
/bin/ls
java/io/IOException
Main
java/lang/Object
java/lang/Runtime
getRuntime
()Ljava/lang/Runtime;
exec
'(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Process;
```

As you can see, `/bin/ls` can be identified as a string. This should work in most cases, unless your Java program is constructing commands in a weird way, like using a char array to create command strings during runtime just to obscure the commands being executed (in which case I'd be highly suspicious of such a program).

However, if you want to see the commands executing in real time, I'm afraid you'll need to resort to some monitoring utility, since most commands would be too short-lived to even appear on `top` and the like.

EDIT: Regarding `strace`: I had a look at [Java's native C code for UNIX systems](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/modules/jdk/file/a37326fa7f95/src/solaris/native/java/lang/UNIXProcess_md.c) and it seems that it actually uses the `execvpe()` system call to run all commands launched with `Runtime.exec()`:

```
    execvpe(argv[0], argv, envv);
```

So, in theory, you should be able to run `strace -e execvpe <java command...>` to list every command executed (as well as every other call to `execvpe()` -- you'll need to filter a bit more, that's true).

Comment: Hmm, thank you. This is interesting... Do you know at least names of that utilities? I tried `strace` and `jstack -m`...

Comment: I took a look around and found this: http://superuser.com/questions/222912/how-can-i-log-all-process-launches-in-linux. Alternatively, and now I'm just thinking out loud, you could: create a user `new_user`, write a script that runs `ps -U new_user > output.txt` in a loop in one terminal, and run the jar as `new_user` in a different terminal. Every command `exec()`d by the jar should run as `new_user` too, so when the Java program finishes, just kill the `ps` script and inspect the `output.txt` file.

Comment: See, the problem with `jstack` is that it prints stack trace information only, which doesn't include parameter values. So you might see the call to `Runtime.exec()` but won't see the string it received as a parameter, i.e. the command it is executing. Regarding strace, I'm editing my answer to make it better and maybe help you further. Anyways, if you want a tool-oriented solution, you might be better off asking at [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) instead of here.